# How to delete given string from list elements in Python?

Tags: python

How to find and replace given string from list elements?

Comment: Example list:   one 1, one 2, one 3 . Given string - one. I want to get - 1, 2,  3

Comment: Update your question with that information. Folks shouldn't have to read the comments to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Fair enough. What attempts have you made to try to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate the `list` and reassign each element to be itself but with the string in question replaced by nothing.

```
for idx,item in enumerate(my_list):
    my_list[idx] = my_list[idx].replace(removed_string, '')
```

Comment: `[item.replace('one', '') for item in l]` would more simply do the same thing...

Comment: @heinst: Not exactly the same thing — that is building a new list as opposed to updating the existing one as this answer does.

Comment: you could just reassign the list then @martineau `my_list = [item.replace('one', '') for item in my_list`.. same thing

Comment: @heinst: Of course, but that requires additional processing.